# Why is there no Maltese Cross in this non-precision approach chart which has a FAF?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, non-precision-approach

[image: **enter image description here**]

I am wondering why this chart does not show the FAF with a maltese cross as it is used in non-precision approaches to depict FAF.
The chart’s briefing strip refers to D6.0 as the FAF and on the plan view FD23 code can be seen(which also indicates that this the FAF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a charting issue.  It is also the same for the NDB Z Rwy 23 approach into LTAY.    Feel free to ask Jeppesen and they will tell you if the chart is in error.

https://support.jeppesen.com/