# Why is there no Maltese Cross in this non-precision approach's profile view which has a FAF?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, ils, non-precision-approach, precision-approach

[image]I am wondering why this chart does not show the FAF with a maltese cross as it is used in non-precision approaches to depict FAF. [image]

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/75458/567

Answer (score -1):

Turkey does not indicate the FAF on their charts, so Jeppesen is not going to add one to their format. There’s nothing more to it than that.